# XSLT 1.0 Group by reservationDate

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xpath-1.0

I have the following XML data:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="serverReserve_1.xsl" ?>
  <!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->


  <reservation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="localSchema.xsd">
    <new>
      <name>Ah Huat</name>
      <icNum>930330033330</icNum>
      <contact>0182345679</contact>
      <reserveDate>20150402</reserveDate>
      <reserveTime>08:00am</reserveTime>
      <day>4</day>
      <totalPeople>2</totalPeople>
      <room unit="2" type="King Suite">
        <bedType>King Bed</bedType>
        <extraRequirement>One more quilt</extraRequirement>
        <extraRequirement>One more bed</extraRequirement>
      </room>
    </new>

    <new>
      <name>Ah Huat</name>
      <icNum>930330033330</icNum>
      <contact>0182345679</contact>
      <reserveDate>20150402</reserveDate>
      <reserveTime>08:00am</reserveTime>
      <day>4</day>
      <totalPeople>2</totalPeople>
      <room unit="2" type="King Suite">
        <bedType>King Bed</bedType>
        <extraRequirement>One more quilt</extraRequirement>
        <extraRequirement>One more bed</extraRequirement>
      </room>
    </new>

    <new>
      <name>Ah Huat</name>
      <icNum>930330033330</icNum>
      <contact>0182345679</contact>
      <reserveDate>20150414</reserveDate>
      <reserveTime>08:00am</reserveTime>
      <day>4</day>
      <totalPeople>2</totalPeople>
      <room unit="2" type="King Suite">
        <bedType>King Bed</bedType>
        <extraRequirement>One more quilt</extraRequirement>
        <extraRequirement>One more bed</extraRequirement>
      </room>
    </new>

    <delete>
      <name>Hoo Chee Sem</name>
      <icNum>930110011101</icNum>
      <reserveDate>20150411</reserveDate>
      <reserveTime>08:00am</reserveTime>
      <room unit="2" type="Hillview Deluxe">
        <bedType>2 Single Bed</bedType>
      </room>
    </delete>

    <roomList>
      <rooms code="R1">Single Room</rooms>
      <rooms code="R2">Double Room</rooms>
      <rooms code="R3">Twin Room</rooms>
      <rooms code="R4">Duplex Room</rooms>
      <rooms code="R5">King Suite</rooms>
      <rooms code="R6">Hillview Deluxe</rooms>
      <rooms code="R7">Seaview Deluxe</rooms>
    </roomList>

    <bedList>
      <beds code="B1">Single Bed</beds>
      <beds code="B2">2 Single Beds</beds>
      <beds code="B3">King Bed</beds>
      <beds code="B4">2 King Beds</beds>
      <beds code="B5">Queen Bed</beds>
      <beds code="B6">2 Queen Beds</beds>
      <beds code="B7">3 Queen Beds</beds>
    </bedList>
  </reservation>
```

In XSLT 1.0, I want to group by reserveDate and calculate the counts of reserveDate. So in the above data, I will need a table that shows the reserveDate and the total of reservation made on that date.

How can I do this in XSLT 1.0?
When I try using this method it gave me an error saying "Parsing an XSLT stylesheet failed."

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" />
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>

    <head>
      <title>reserve.xsl</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <xsl:key name="groups" match="/reservation/new" use="reserveDate" />

      <xsl:template match="/reservation">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="new[generate-id() = generate-id(key('groups', reserveDate)[1])]" />
      </xsl:template>
      <xsl:template match="new">
        <h1>
                        <xsl:value-of select="reserveDate"/>
                    </h1>
        <table id="{reserveDate}">
          <tr class="heading">
            <th scope="col">Member Id</th>
            <th scope="col">First Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="key('groups', reserveDate)">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="name" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="reserveTime" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="contact" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </xsl:template>
    </body>

    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Is that your **entire** stylesheet? Where is the `xsl:stylesheet` root element?

Comment: My xsl:stylesheet root elements are <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>  

    <xsl:template match="/">

Comment: Please do not post code in comments - edit your question instead, and include your complete stylesheet, not blocks for us to assemble. FWIW, your original code works for me, if I paste it into a `xsl:stylesheet` element.

Comment: Post edited. I still couldn't get mine to work

Comment: Well, that's a completely different stylesheet than the one before. Note: **1.** `xsl:key` cannot be inside a template; **2.** a template cannot be inside another template.

Comment: Oh! So how am I going to modify this? Im still a beginner and learning so I'm not too sure how to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your XSLT as follows - move the template matching `reservation` outside of the template matching the root level:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">    
<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:key name="groups" match="/reservation/new" use="reserveDate" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <hmtl>
      <head>
        <title>reserve.xsl</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </hmtl>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/reservation">
    ....
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the template matching root, `apply templates` which will call the template matching `reservation`:

```
<body>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</body>
```

[Demo](http://xsltransform.net/nc4NzQy)